Finding Sony "star ratings" in image metadata
A number of Sony cameras allow "star ratings" from 1 to 5 stars to be assigned to photos in-camera.
These can be used by selected software for subsequent sorting and selection.
I wish to use these star ratings in editing software that does not explicitly support them.
I assume that they are available as metadata via an EXIF address or similar.
Some while ago I made extensive unsuccessful efforts to locate them in the image data.
A web search finds mentions of this rating system but no advice on locations.
Can anyone advise where these ratings are stored in image data, EXIF or other.
I have an A7RIV but the feature is available in other recent Somy cameras.

There is a Rating tag that can be found in the EXIF group, but it is not part of the EXIF specification, and is marked by exiftool as a tag to avoid writing. This tag originated with MicrosoftPhoto and unlikely to be read by any programs other than Microsoft ones.
It is probably more likely that a Sony camera will be writing to the Sony specific Rating tag, which can be found in the Sony MakerNotes.
Very few programs will read MakerNotes tags. Camera companies don't share the specs on how they are formatted, and the formatting is constantly changing.
Your best bet is to copy the rating to the more standardized location, XMP:Rating. You can do this in batch using this exiftool command
exiftool "-XMP:Rating<Rating" /path/to/files/
This command creates backup files.  Add -overwrite_original to suppress the creation of backup files.  Add -r to recurse into subdirectories.
